# java.sql.DriverManager not prepared for test

Tags: java, junit, mocking, powermock, powermockito

I have a test which throws the following error..

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl  to method java.lang.Object.clone()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

org.powermock.api.mockito.ClassNotPreparedException: 

[Ljava.lang.Object;@383caf89
The class java.sql.DriverManager not prepared for test.
```

I have minimized my test to the following code to narrow it down

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.*;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.*;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;


import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;


@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({DriverManager.class, ClassCallingDriverManager.class})
public class ClassCallingDriverManagerTest{

    @Test
    public void testMethod() throws SQLException {
        final Connection connection = mock(Connection.class);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(DriverManager.class);
    }

}
```

Here are my dependencies in my pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I have no idea what is causing this error when I do mockStatic().  Am I doing this right?  I was trying to test the DriverManager.getConnection() method, but it kept failing on this call so I removed the code until I narrowed it down to this line.

Comment: Have you figure out the solution? I am facing same issue